# Proving the integral of a discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

> > Let $y_n$ be a monotone decreasing sequence with $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0$. Define the function $f:\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
> >     $$
> > f(x)=
> > \begin{cases}
> > y_n          &\text {there exists $n$ such that $x=y_n$,}\\
> > 0&\text{otherwise.}
> > \end{cases}
> > $$
> >     Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $\left[0,1\right]$ and that $\int_{0}^{1}{f}\,dx=0$.

My attempt:

Given $\varepsilon>0$, there are only a finite number of points in $[0,1]$ with $ f(x)\geq\varepsilon$. Let $M_{\varepsilon} $be this number and consider a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $[0,1] $ into subintervals $[x_{i-1},x_{i}].$

On each subinterval $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ there are two possibilities: either

1) $0\leq f(x)<\varepsilon $ for all $x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}], $ or

2) there exists $t_{i}\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ such that $\varepsilon\leq f(t_{i})\leq 1$

There are at most $2M_{\varepsilon}$ intervals of the second kind.
(The factor of two is because we could have a tag point on the edge of
an interval. $t_{i}=x_{i}=t_{i+1}$.)

Choose $\displaystyle \delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2M_{\varepsilon}}.$ Then, for any tagged partition$ \dot{\mathcal{P}}$ with size $||\dot{\mathcal{P}}||<\delta, $ we have the following bound for the Riemann sum

$0\displaystyle \leq \mathcal{S}(f,\dot{\mathcal{P}})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1}) 
< \varepsilon(1-0)+2M_{\varepsilon}\cdot\delta
=\varepsilon(1-0)+\varepsilon=2\varepsilon$

Therefore$, \displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f dx=0.$

Comment: Looks perfectly ok to me. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good. This argument is a bit more technical, but I think it is more geometrically intuitive as well, so I thought it was worth showing. Here I will assume $y_n$ is strictly decreasing; this does not change $f$ but is merely required for clarity of indexing. Similarly I assume $y_1 \leq 1$ (if not, then cutting off the first however many terms necessary does not change $f$).

Notice that the lower sum for any partition is always zero.

Notice that the integral is bounded above by the upper sum of any particular partition. So we can *choose* the partitions $P_{N,\delta} = \{ 0,y_{N-1}-\delta,y_{N-1}+\delta,\dots,y_1-\delta,y_1+\delta,1 \}$ The first interval contributes at most $y_N$ to the upper sum. Assuming the sequence above is strictly increasing, the interval around $y_i$ contributes at most $2 \delta y_i$ to the upper sum, which is in particular at most $2 \delta$. There are $N-1$ such intervals. The intervals "between" the $y_i$ contribute nothing. So overall the upper sum is less than $y_N + 2N \delta$.

Therefore, given $\varepsilon > 0$, we can choose $N$ so that $y_N < \varepsilon/2$ and then choose $\delta$ so that both $2 N \delta < \varepsilon/2$ and so that the sequence of partition points is increasing. The $N$ comes from the modulus of convergence of the sequence. To precisely handle $\delta$, we can assume

$$\delta = \min \{ \varepsilon/4N, (y_1-y_2)/4, (y_3-y_2)/4, \dots, (y_N - y_{N-1})/4 \}.$$

Then the upper sum is at most $\varepsilon$ and so we are done.